# Editor for use with GoogleAppEngineLauncher on Mac

Tags: python, google-app-engine, editor, directory, yaml

What editors are best for use with the "Edit" button in GoogleAppEngineLauncher for Mac? A good editor would preferably be able to edit Python and YAML and be able to open directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use your favorite editor? Textmate or gvim or emacs anything should do here. All them support Python and YAML syntax.

Comment: +1 for TextMate, it's sophisticated enough to help but simple enough not to get in the way.

Answer (score 1):

[Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download) is really good.  It's a little heavyweight, but does Python syntax highlighting and code completion, and YAML syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried TextWrangler or jEdit? You can get the links to them on Apple site or you can google for them. They are pretty good editors.

Comment: I've tried TextWrangler, but not only does it not have support for YAML, it doesn't even show .yaml files in the file browser to be edited normally.